# javascript es6 comma-separated object into string array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using React JS and have a multi-select widget where I would like to get all the selected values and put each value in a string array.  I was able to get all the selected values into a comma-separated object using this code:

```
 [...event.target.options].filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value)
```

This produces an output like this:  `value1, value3`

I was able to add single-quotes to each value as well like this:

```
 [...event.target.options].filter(o => o.selected).map(o => `'${o.value}`)
```

This produces the following output: `'value1', 'value3'`

But I don't know how to get the result into an array-- I want something like this:

```
['value1','value3']
```

Any ideas on how to do this with JS, preferably ES6?

Comment: Can you please provide a data example of `event.target.options`

Comment: but isnt `.map()` supposed to return an array already?

Comment: `map()` returns an array. What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be nothing wrong with your code, the code causing unexpected results must be happening somewhere else. Maybe you are using `.join` on the array somewhere.

```js
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener(
  "change",
  e=>
    console.log(
       [...event.target.options]
      .filter(o => o.selected)
      .map(o => o.value)
    )
);
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</seclect>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it already is an array?

```js
var event = {
  target: {
    options: [
      {
        value: 'value1',
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: 'value2',
        selected: true
      },
      {
        value: 'value3',
        selected: false
      },
    ]
    
  }
};

var output = [...event.target.options].filter(o => o.selected).map(o => `${o.value}`)
console.log(output);
console.log(Array.isArray(output));
```

Comment: for some reason that didn't work for me when I tried that, just returns 'value1', 'value3'.  Also created an explicit array and tried to push the values-- same issue.